# how to select a specific character on a specific place

Tags: regex, python-3.x

My question goes about the following list of data.

```
data = ['TNNI3', 'TSHZ3/THEG5', 'ACTR3BP2-', 'BIN1/CYP27C1',
'-', 'NBPF1/NBPF20', 'ERBB4', '-NBPF20', '-']
```

I need to select the character "-" only if is combined with something else. In case it stand by it self, it needs to stay unselected.

For example the "-" in 'ACTR3BP2-' and '-NBPF20' needs to be selected and the two '-' in the list needs to stay unselected.

Does anyone know how to do this by using regex in python3??

Once the correct "-" are selected I want to remove them from the list.
How I think to do this is to use the re.sub function and replace it with an empty space. If someone has a better idea to do this. I'm glad to hear them!

Comment: Do you want to remove the `-` elements? [`[x for x in data if x != '-']`](http://ideone.com/Y16Ihf)? Or just extract those elements that contain `-` but not equal to it - [`[x for x in data if '-' in x and x != '-']`](http://ideone.com/Lvs4Hs)?

Comment: See my answer for Python 3 regex solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to do this if you don't require regex.  Doing a string compare and replace would be faster than using Regex.

```
import re

data = ['TNNI3', 'TSHZ3/THEG5', 'ACTR3BP2-', 'BIN1/CYP27C1',
       '-', 'NBPF1/NBPF20', 'ERBB4', '-NBPF20', '-']

for e in data:
    if "-" in e and e != "-":
        old = e
        new = e.replace("-", "")
        print(old + " >> " + new)
```